# D3.js: Don't start new transition until the previous one has finished?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a D3 graph alongside a Google Map. I want the graph to transition whenever the map zoom changes. It works fine if the zoom doesn't change faster than the transition has finished updating. However, clicking zoom twice in succession leads to broken transitions.

How can I stop the next transition starting before the previous transition has finished?

This is my code (it's a Backbone app):

```
    render: function() { 
      this.renderMap();
    },
    renderMap: function() {
      var that = this; 
      ...
      google.maps.event.addListener(that.mapControl, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        that.change();
      });
    },
    change: function() {
      var that = this;
      d3.transition().duration(750).each(function() {
        that.redraw();
      });
    },
    redraw: function() {
      ...
      this.redraw = function() {
        ...
        var barUpdate = d3.transition(bar).attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(0," + (d.y0 = y(d.State)) + ")";
        }).style("fill-opacity", 1);
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think that you might be able to separate your transitions by adding a delay based on the index.

```
.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .delay(function(d, i){
        return i * 750
  })
```

If you're looking for the exact moment that a transition ends, you can try adding the .each("end", listener) to the transition() which will call the listener at a transition's end. [Transitions#Control](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each). Making the code look something like this?

```
.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .each("end", that.redraw())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this idea. I have about 20 events I need to fire as a 'cursor' sweeps across a graph. I will give it a shot and check it out.

Comment: Everyone should keep in mind this important note from the documentation: `Note that if the transition is superseded by a later-scheduled transition on a given element, no end event will be dispatched for that element; interrupted transitions do not trigger end events.`